# Efficient query to select distinct combination of rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 3 tables in a database: firewall, interface and changes.

- firewall has 2 columns: `id` and `name`.
- interface has 3 columns: `id`, `firewall id` and `name` where `firewall id` is the firewall primary key.
- changes has several columns, including the `firewall id` and the `interface id`. Let's call these other columns `changes.id`, `firewall id`, `interface id`, `port` `src`, and `dest` where `changes.id` is the changes primary key and auto increments.

`changes` will eventually have thousands or millions of rows of data.

I need a query that will select the LAST set of unique combinations of `firewall id`, `interface id`, `src`, `dest`, and `port` from `changes`. I say last, because in time, there will most likely be exact duplicates.

I have a query that will do this, but I think it will be very CPU expensive when this table gets big:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.name, i.name, changes.a, changes.b, src, dest, port FEOM changes INNER JOIN firewall f ON changes.a = f.id INNER JOIN interface i ON changes.b = i.id ORDER BY changes.id DESC;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see a lot of ifs in your question.  Are you actively trying to optimize a query on a very large table, or are you seeking hypothetical advice?

Comment: One way is to add an unique index on (interface ,a,b,c) and use a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, assuming you only want to keep the latest combinations.

Comment: I'm building the design for a new query on a new database that doesn't have any data yet, but will be populated whenever we make a change to a firewall. So a little of both. Maybe I should be more specific with field names instead of a, b and c. We're tracking source IP address, destination IP address, and port number.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to edit for clarity on what the data actually is in the changes table.

Comment: What's the purpose of the queried data? Should they describe the current state of the firewalls? Or maybe you just want *the* last change/s for a/some/all firewall/s?

Comment: Actually, I want status of all interfaces on each firewall, for each source IP to destination IP on each port, hence selecting the unique combination of things. I.e. "10.1.0.1 -> 10.1.0.2 on port 80" and "10.1.0.1 -> 10.1.0.2" on port 443 would be 2 separate changes, and since they deal with different ports, they need to be included in the query.